# Desinstalar plugin no sublime

Tags: sublime-text

Preciso remover o plugin SFTP do sublime.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu ja desinstalei e instalei de novo, e estou fazendo deploy pelo Fillezila, mas o sublime fica tentando conectar ao FTP toda vez...

Preciso remover essa configuração do SFTP ou desinstalar o plugin, como faço isso?

*Eu utilizava o notepad++ estou me adaptando ao sublime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para quem precisar remover um plugin no sublime, segue as orientações abaixo:

---

Ctrl + shift + p

*Digitar: package control: remove package

**Selecionar o plugin que deseja remover...

É isso, obrigado!